# I can’t download the package BMR from github in R, it gives an error:

Tags: r

```
> library(devtools)

Download required package: usethis

Warning messages:
1: package ‘devtools' was built under R version 3.5.3 
2: package ‘usethis’ was built under R version 3.5.3 

> install_github("kthohr/BMR",force=TRUE)
Downloading GitHub repo kthohr/BMR@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqkzAt0\remotes4b403a3737ba\kthohr-BMR-63565cd/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  preparing 'BMR': (3.1s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (1.1s)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories (362ms)
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'BMR_0.11.0.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Asus/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'BMR' ...
** libs
Ошибка: (конвертировано из предупреждения) this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture
* removing 'C:/Users/Asus/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/BMR'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error: Failed to install 'BMR' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqkzAt0/file4b4017187131/BMR_0.11.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: How did you download the package? What did you then do to try to install it?

Comment: Hi Alina, please show us all the steps you used to get to the error, and also your `sessionInfo()` so we can cut and paste the code and reproduce your problem locally. This will help people provide potential answer to you. Thanks :)

Comment: install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("kthohr/BMR", INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")

Comment: All this error tells us is that it failed. You'll have to share more information for anyone to stand a chance at helping you.

Comment: [related](https://github.com/kthohr/BMR/issues/36).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("kthohr/BMR",force=TRUE)
```

Comment: > library(devtools)
downloading the required package: usethis
Warning messages:
1: the package ‘devtools’ was created for  R version 3.5.3 
2: the package ‘usethis’ was created for  R version 3.5.3

Comment: I understand your concern, this is because you are using different version of R, but did this install the `BMR` package.

Answer (score 0):

Please install `Rtolls` direct its path on `R`. Then use the following codes.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("kthohr/BMR")
library(BMR)
find_rtools()
```

**This to check if rtolls is installed.**

If still not working please reinstall `R`, `Rstudio` and `Rtools` then again try running it. It worked in my case.
To check if the package is installed try opening on of the data sets included in the package.

data(BMRMCData)